# winjs appnavigation background

Tags: javascript, html, winjs

I to created a project for windows 8 in javascripts/html. Now I want change the background of body when I change page.
I tried to set the background body but when I navigate into the app and I use the backbutton the backgroud don't update correctly. The problem is that remains the last background of the previus page.

Answer (score 1):

If you're setting the background through each page's CSS, it won't work because CSS is cumulative across WinJS page navigations. That is, because you're just doing DOM replacement and not actually navigating away from the main host page (default.html typically), then each time you hit a page control HTML file that loads another CSS file for the first time, that new CSS gets loaded on top of the old. However, going back to a page that references a CSS file that's already been loaded will not force a reload.

There are a few strategies for handling this, but if you're setting a style on body then it's easiest to set the background style from JavaScript within each page's processed or ready methods, and not rely on the CSS loading behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You have probably only one body in all your app, so you have to change it to the right background every time youenter a page, included the first page.

I suggest you do it in the ready event of every page so that it will refresh also when you click on the backbutton.